# How to populate a dropdown that depend on another dropdown, both in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have one table, objects, with two columns: id and name.
second table, objectAttributes, with four columns: id, name, mainAttr and objectId that reference the first table column. mainAttr is a boolean that indicate that this attribute is the default.
I want to create a table for the user with variable number of rows (the logic for that is irrelevant) and in each row I want two dropdowns: one for objects from table 1 above, and the second for the attribute that **belong** to that object. When the user change dropdown 1 of objects, dropdown two has to change too and the default attribute should be chosen.
This is something I tried to do:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="(parentIndex, data) in p">
       <td >{{data.ColumnName}}</td>
       <td >
          <select ng-model="data.ObjectId" ng-options="x.OBJECT_ID as x.OBJECT_NAME for x in objectsList" ng-change="hasAllObjectId()" style="width:100%">
             <option value="">---</option>
          </select>
       </td> 
       <td >
          <select  ng-options="x.OBJECT_ID as x.OBJECT_NAME for x in objectsAttributeList" ng-change="hasAllObjectId()" style="width:100%">
             <option value="">---</option>
          </select>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

This is how it should look like:

[Using **ng-repeat**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VR1L.png)

The server is WebAPI. 
Does someone know a proper way to handle this ?

Comment: Maybe this blog post about cascading dropdowns can help you: https://miparnisariblog.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/cascading-dropdowns-with-angularjs/

Comment: @miparnisari, In the blog post the dropdowns are not in ng-repeat. This is not the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    

    $scope.values = 
       [
           {
               "name": "value1",
               "version":
               [
                   "10"
               ]
           },
           {
               "name": "value2",
               "version":
               [
                   "1", "2"
               ]
           }
       ];

    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <select ng-model="value" ng-options="x.name for x in values"></select>
        <select ng-model="version" ng-options="val for val in value.version"></select>
    </div>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: The select elements are not in ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you provide your json structure.

Comment: I described the tables structure from that you can create a json structure.

Comment: I don't have any.